# oracle sql date format to only seconds

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm trying to convet a timestamp to seconds.

I read that you could do it this way

```
to_char(to_date(10000,'sssss'),'hh24:mi:ss')
```

But turns out this way you can't go over 86399 seconds.

This is my date format: +000000000 00:00:00.000000

What's the best approach to converting this to seconds? (this is the result of subtracting two dates to find the difference).

Comment: You subtracted timestamp1 from timestamp2 and want to know how many seconds that is?

Comment: @DanBracuk yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to find the total number of seconds in an `interval` (which is the  datatype returned when you subtract two `timestamps`). In order to convert the `interval` to seconds, you need to `extract` each component and convert them to seconds. Here's an example:

```
SELECT interval_value,
         (EXTRACT (DAY FROM interval_value) * 24 * 60 * 60)
       + (EXTRACT (HOUR FROM interval_value) * 60 * 60)
       + (EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM interval_value) * 60)
       + EXTRACT (SECOND FROM interval_value)
          AS interval_in_sec
FROM   (SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP - TRUNC (SYSTIMESTAMP - 1) AS interval_value
        FROM   DUAL)
```

Comment: SYSTIMESTAMP - 1 convert your timestamp to a date!

Comment: @eliatou: True, but subtracting a `date` from a `timestamp` results in an `interval`, which is the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert timestamp to date by adding a number (zero in our case).
Oracle downgrade then the type from timestamp to date

ex:

```
select systimestamp+0  as sysdate_ from dual
```

and the difference in secondes between 2 timestamp:

```
SQL> select 24*60*60*
       ((SYSTIMESTAMP+0)
        -(TO_TIMESTAMP('16-MAY-1414:10:10.123000','DD-MON-RRHH24:MI:SS.FF')+0)
        ) 
     diff_ss from dual;

   DIFF_SS
 ----------
   15140
```

Comment: While I love this solution, I'm getting a rather peculiar issue: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer - particularly for whoever has to maintain the code - to do `cast(systimestamp as date)` etc. rather than add the arbitrary zero and rely on the date time arithmetic?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat: Could you give up your code? For me it working perfectly

Comment: @Alex Poole. You're right, doing a cast(systimestamp as date) is maybe clearer. But for me the most clearer is a simple comment to explain why you are doing that!  For me I often do that when I have to read some column with timestamp just because it's human readable! So +0 is easier to write than a cast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of seconds between two dates (or timestamps),

```
select floor(
(to_date(to_char(timestamp1, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss') 
- to_date(to_char(timestamp2, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss')
 )    
* 24 -- hours per day
* 60 -- minutes per hour
* 60 -- seconds per minute
)
etc
```

Comment: This only works for `date` types, not `timestamp`. Subtracting two `timestamp` values results in an `interval`, which can't be operated on as simply.

Comment: That is correct.  Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer - particularly for whoever has to maintain the code - and simpler to do `cast(timestamp1 as date)` etc. rather than converting to and from strings?